# LG UltraGear 24GL600F-B - How can I get rid of these compression artifacts?

Tags: display

I purchased 2 of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NHSJ1RF) (LG UltraGear 24GL600F-B) monitors recently and have been having trouble getting the colors right for the past few days now. I like my brightness a little lower, but have not been able to get a good looking picture. Here's what I mean: [Reference image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/477361590212231168/792568755561299988/photo-1557683316-973673baf926.png) vs [what I see.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/477361590212231168/792568850595708958/unknown.png) Every scene I look at whether it's in a show or a game just looks awful. Currently the monitors are connected to my graphics card [(Asus 1060 3GB)](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics-Cards/DUAL-GTX1060-O3G/) with the provided HDMI cables.

How can I fix this? It's happening on both monitors. Here are the settings I am using now:

---

Game Mode: Gamer 1

FreeSync: Off

Black Stabilizer: 50

Response time: Fast (Both are set to 144Hz on Windows 10)

Brightness: 20 (It's easier on my eyes. If I need to raise it then so be it.)

Contrast: 75

Sharpness: 50

Gamma: Mode 2

Color Temp: Medium

R/G/B: N/A

Six Color: All set to 50

Black Level: High

DFC: Off

Comment: That has nothing to do with "compression artifacts". It is [colour banding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_banding) and is almost entirely a feature of the panel itself. Many "fast" monitors sacrifice bit depth for being able to change the image quickly.

Comment: The [reviews for that monitor](https://www.rtings.com/monitor/reviews/lg/24gl600f) suggest it is generally a bad screen. "Unfortunately, like most TN monitors, it has poor viewing angles, low contrast, and bad black uniformity, which results in mediocre overall picture quality." and "The LG UltraGear 24GL600F-B only supports 8-bit color, so there is noticeable 8-bit banding in our 10-bit test image."

Comment: Check this image - simple black>white vignette, 8-bit jpg from a known source (me ;) at 1920x1080, the size of your displays. Add a photo of the screen as you did your full colour vignette. You will see banding definitely on the lower quadrant but the top end should be clean on an sRGB monitor. 8-bit will always band on vignettes, but shouldn't be as bad as your photo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA8qK.jpg